# How do I launch a QPython Script from MIT App Inventor Activity Starter and exit cleanly?

Tags: android, app-inventor, qpython

I have made a simple training app with MIT App Inventor 2. The app logs to a logfile, and I've made a small QPython script to analyze the log and display stats.

I'd like to use the Activity Starter to launch my Python script, but I haven't been able to figure out the correct set of Action, ActivityClass, ActivityPackage and Extra[x] to make it work. I've run adb on my Android phone to find the correct strings but I get a "601 No corresponding activity was found" when I try.

Here's the adb output grepped for "qpyplus" while running the script:

```
I/Timeline( 1898): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.hipipal.qpyplus time:15752330
I/ActivityManager(  862): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.hipipal.qpyplus/com.hipipal.qpylib.MPyApi bnds=[540,456][807,756] (has extras)} from uid 10116 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  862): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{1687ec32 token=Token{120bbc3d ActivityRecord{1ef9e994 u0 com.hipipal.qpyplus/com.hipipal.qpylib.MPyApi t5112}}} to stack=1 task=5112 at 0
V/WindowManager(  862): Adding window Window{e90d72c u0 Starting com.hipipal.qpyplus} at 18 of 26 (after Window{30168e12 u0 edu.mit.appinventor.aicompanion3/edu.mit.appinventor.aicompanion3.Screen1})
I/Timeline(31680): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.hipipal.qpyplus time:15752447
I/ActivityManager(  862): START u0 {cmp=com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term (has extras)} from uid 10335 on display 0
V/WindowManager(  862): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{382fc5e2 token=Token{1e492ead ActivityRecord{2e34dfc4 u0 com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term t5112}}} to stack=1 task=5112 at 1
V/WindowManager(  862): Based on layer: Adding window Window{e90d72c u0 Starting com.hipipal.qpyplus} at 18 of 26
V/WindowManager(  862): Adding window Window{390e635c u0 com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term} at 18 of 27 (before Window{e90d72c u0 Starting com.hipipal.qpyplus})
I/ActivityManager(  862): Displayed com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term: +117ms (total +245ms)
I/Timeline(  862): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{2e34dfc4 u0 com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term t5112} time:15752597
```

I've read the [docs](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html) and tried to decipher the logs and populate the tags. I've also found an old answer from 2010 to the same sort of question, but it seems that QPython has moved on since then because the recipe doesn't correspond to my logcat (and also doesn't work). Please see screenshot of both options (I'm a rookie here so I'm not allowed to embed images).

[screenshot of two options that don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bAJw.png)
[image]
Does anybody know how I should format the Activity Starter for this script to run?

**Update!**
Taifun has put me on the right track, I think. I've followed his advice and re-compiled the .apk with new permissions and installed it so that it will be allowed to run a shell script. My problem now is that QPython seems to completely ignore my asking it to run a script on startup. The terminal opens okay, but my script doesn't run. If I run the command manually, it runs just fine.

Any thoughts?

[My new config that almost works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIRnJ.png)

Comment: see the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html) how to set the properties... you might want to try something and post a screenshot of your blocks...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Taifun. I did read the docs but neglected to say that or post a screenshot. Sorry! I've edited my question accordingly.

Comment: What happens, if you use action= `android.intent.action.MAIN`, package=`com.hipipal.qpyplus` and class=`com.hipipal.qpylib.MPyApi`? Can you provide a link to that information from the net you found?

Comment: Thanks @Taifun! With your suggestions I get the QPython log view, but not any script output. It just says "Python script is running". I don't know if it is running the intended script or not as I haven't found a way of specifying it yet.

The post from 2010 where they'd supposedly made it work is [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/appinventor/qIu9hX1tLdo/ilkVqigEjEYJ).

Thanks again for your help! I don't know how to specify which script to run and can't find any specific reference to my script in the logcat output.

Comment: That link describes how to use [SL4A](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) together with App Inventor, see also my [App Inventor Classic example here](https://puravidaapps.com/countdown1.php). Alternatively you could run a shell script instead, see also [this snippet](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2terminal), which uses the Jackpal Terminal Emulator.

Comment: Thanks again @taifun. I'd like to run this as a Shell script, but since I haven't rooted my device I cannot browse /data/data to find the python executable. Ang suggestions on how to find qpython executable from jackpal?

Comment: I've found the path to the executable, but I'm not allowed to run it without root permissions. Since I'm not allowed to run this from jackpal, I'll keep on trying to make qpython run my script, since it has the correct permissions. I still haven't figured out how to set up the ExtraKey and ExtraValue to run the specific script. The logcat output tells me that the qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term "has extras", but then it becomes a bit muddy. If anyone knows which parameters I should pass through ExtraKey and ExtraValue from the logcat dump above, I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: The data must be somewhere here, but I can't figure it out:
{cmp=com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term (has extras)} from uid 10335 on display 0
**V/WindowManager(  861): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{20bf5c1 token=Token{c40c6a8 ActivityRecord{7ca3ecb u0 com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term t5248}}} to stack=1 task=5248 at 2**
V/WindowManager(  861): Adding window Window{21036df2 u0 com.hipipal.qpyplus/jackpal.androidterm.Term} at 20 of 28 (after Window{1199c59a u0 PopupWindow:19603529 EXITING})

Comment: Update above. Taifun has put me on the right track, but I'm not all the way there yet. QPython starts but won't run my script on init. Could anyone hazard a guess as to why?

Comment: As already said earlier, use SL4A together with your current script or use the Jackpal Terminal Emulator solution together with a *shell* script. Alternatively analyse the log in App Inventor directly

Comment: Yeah, as I said earlier, jackpal is not allowed to run the Python executable. I'll pursue the SL4A path a bit, then. Thanks again. Maybe I'll just rewrite the whole thing. It's just that I really like Python and really don't like JavaScript ;-)

Comment: did you try to install the [Terminal Emulator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) and run your script there? If you get this running, then it also should run using [my example](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2terminal)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I did try that and the Term itself is not allowed to run the qpython executable. Only the jackpal included in Qpython is allowed... I'm totally with you on how it should work if the terminal were allowed to run python in the first place. Qpython also uses jacpal, but ignores my init parameter for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

http://i.hizliresim.com/mLqgP4.png

```
action="com.hipipal.qpyplus.action.MPyApi"
classname="com.hipipal.qpyplus.MPyApi"
packagename="com.hipipal.qpyplus"
extras={"app" : "appid", "act" : "onPyApi", "flag" : "onQPyExec", "param" : "", "pycode" : "print 'selam'\nprint 'naber'"}
```

This is working fine :)